Polars - when/then conditions form dict
I would like to have a function that accept list of conditions as parameter and filter given dataframe by all of them.
Pseudocode should look like this:
def Filter(df, conditions = ["a","b"]):
    conditions_dict = {
        "a":  pl.col("x") < 5,
        "b":  pl.col("x") > -3,
        "c":  pl.col("z") < 7
        }

    return df.with_columns(
        pl.when( any [conditions_dict[c] for c in conditions])
        .then(pl.lit(False))
        .otherwise(pl.lit(True))
        .alias("bool")
        )

How to do it?

In general, you can create a generator for the filter expressions of interest and pass it to pl.any_horizontal to check whether any of them evaluates to True. This can be used within a pl.when().then().otherwise() construct.
def custom_filter(df: pl.DataFrame, conditions: list[str]) -> pl.DataFrame:
    conditions_dict = {
        "a":  pl.col("x") < 5,
        "b":  pl.col("x") > -3,
        "c":  pl.col("z") < 7
    }
    return df.with_columns(
        pl.when(
            pl.any_horizontal(*(conditions_dict[c] for c in conditions))
        ).then(
            pl.lit(False)
        ).otherwise(
            pl.lit(True)
        ).alias("bool")
    )

custom_filter(df, ["a"])

Note. In the specific example provided, you can simplify and drop the pl.when().then().otherwise() construct and replace it with the negation of the horizontal aggregation ~pl.any_horizontal(...).
shape: (6, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬───────┐
│ x   ┆ z   ┆ bool  │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---   │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ bool  │
╞═════╪═════╪═══════╡
│ -4  ┆ -2  ┆ false │
│ -2  ┆ -3  ┆ false │
│ 1   ┆ 8   ┆ false │
│ 3   ┆ 4   ┆ false │
│ 5   ┆ 2   ┆ true  │
│ 7   ┆ 1   ┆ true  │
└─────┴─────┴───────┘


pl.any_horizontal(*(conditions_dict[c] for c in conditions)) why not pl.any_horizontal(conditions_dict.values())?

@levantpied Because condition_dict is a dictionary mapping all condition labels to their corresponding expressions and conditions is a list of labels of the specific conditions that should be applied. Especially, pl.any_horizontal(conditions_dict.values()) would check for all conditions (and not only those passed to the function).

Makes sense ty!
